# How to Get Data From Document having Special Character In Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from Firestore but getting `null` if document having a special character i.e **São Paulo** and it happened only with **São Paulo**.

Working query:

```
db.collection("streets")
                .document("Arlington")
                .collection("street")
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                List<DocumentSnapshot> docSnap = task.getResult().getDocuments();
            }
        });
```

Not working query:

```
db.collection("streets")
                .document("São Paulo")
                .collection("street")
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                List<DocumentSnapshot> docSnap = task.getResult().getDocuments();
            }
        });
```

How to get data from document if it has special character?

[image: Firestore database structure]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with special characters in Firestore. A document that has the name of `São Paulo` should work perfectly fine. As I see in your schema, this document has no fields in it, that's why is also written in `italic`. So if you try to get that document, this is the expected behaviour.

If you want to get all documents within a collection you need to iterate through `task.getResult()` like in the following lines of code:

```
yourCollectionRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

```
db.collection("streets").document("São Paulo").collection("street").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getString("city"));
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: After the sau paulo, having a collection street and then having a document with details and it is working fine with other document except the sau paulo.

Comment: Try to make a very simple test. Add under your `São Paulo` document a single property, let's say: `name: "Any Name"` and try to get only this document separately `db.collection("streets").document("São Paulo").get()` and you'll see that is working. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I did this but not working and but if i replaced `ã` with  `a` then its working

Comment: You are doing something wrong. I personally tested and it is working. Firestore has no problem with special characters. Show me your data within the `São Paulo` document and the code that you are using.

Comment: I have attached another screenshot. please look into it

Comment: I see now. It doesn't work because you are trying to edit that path and change the `a` to `ã` while in your database the document is added with `a` and **not** with `ã`. So it doesn't work because the path with `ã` does not exist. There is no document named `São Paulo` in your collection. So changing that character over there it doesn't mean that you actually change the name of the document in the database. This operation is not permited in Firestore not even in code. Is it ok now?

Comment: See, your [document](https://ibb.co/MZg56J2) is `Sao Paulo` and **not** `São Paulo`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184528/discussion-between-suraj-bahadur-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Is not, see your own [screenshot](https://ibb.co/MZg56J2). Is underlined with red, see?

Comment: Yes that one was changed from `São Paulo` to `Sao Paulo` to check and it is working with `Sao Paulo`. but not with `São Paulo`

Comment: Show me in your database the document with `São Paulo` and indicate me how that is not working. Provide me a screenshot for that.

Comment: I have added the `São Paulo` document in database and using same above query to get the data but facing same issues.  here is the screenshot 
 https://ibb.co/wLGV9KP

Comment: As I see in your screenshot, there is no problem having `São Paulo` as a document name. So the initial issue is solved. Now, please see my updated answer and tell me if that code works. Should print in this case `São Paulo` because I see there is a single document, right?

Comment: I have used your code still facing same issue and i have data in `São Paulo` . here  is the screenshot of logs .https://ibb.co/Tmkfjzz

Comment: It is said something about an `ArrayList`. I didn't provide you code regarding an `ArrayList`. Just tell me if that `Log.d(TAG, document.getString("city"));` statement works. Is there anything in printed out in your logcat?

Comment: Don't use `task.getResult().getDocuments()`. If you want to get the results in a list, create a list and add each document to that list.

Comment: it is not coming inside `Log.d("Tag", document.getString("city"));`. and if i do `task.getResult().getDocuments()` with other name then it works but not with `São Paulo`

Comment: I need to see your code. There is something wrong there. It is not about the special character at all.

Comment: You were right, `compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1' , it was set in build.gradle file and thats why it created the problem with special character. Thank you for your help
`